# gdalwarp fails to reproject to 3857

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, grass-gis, gdalwarp

I'm trying to reproject a EPSG 3035 geotif to a EPSG 3857 using gdalwarp as follows:

```
gdalwarp -tap -tr 100 100 -s_srs EPSG:3035 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co 
SPARSE_OK=TRUE -co predictor=2 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co 
TILED=YES -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS source.tif target.tif
```

The source tif is generated in GRASS (7.2) and correctly displayed in qgis while the target one contains only nan. 
The source tif has the following metadata (gdalinfo):

```
PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",
GEOGCS["grs80",
    DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
        SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],
PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],
PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (944300.000000000000000,5413400.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GRASS GIS 7.2.1 with GDAL 2.1.2
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  944300.000, 5413400.000) ( 54d53' 7.79"W, 56d24'16.47"N)
Lower Left  (  944300.000,  942200.000) ( 23d33' 5.25"W, 24d48'30.69"N)
Upper Right ( 6525800.000, 5413400.000) ( 60d11'18.71"E, 64d12'38.48"N)
Lower Right ( 6525800.000,  942200.000) ( 32d24'30.12"E, 28d34'52.61"N)
Center      ( 3735050.000, 3177800.000) (  1d33'27.09"E, 51d24'20.50"N)
Band 1 Block=55815x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
```

In order to generate the source tif I used some other tifs that show the following metadata:

```
PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",
GEOGCS["ETRS89",
    DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],
PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],
PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]
Origin = (944300.000000000000000,5413400.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  944300.000, 5413400.000) ( 54d53' 7.79"W, 56d24'16.47"N)
Lower Left  (  944300.000,  942200.000) ( 23d33' 5.25"W, 24d48'30.69"N)
Upper Right ( 6525800.000, 5413400.000) ( 60d11'18.71"E, 64d12'38.48"N)
Lower Right ( 6525800.000,  942200.000) ( 32d24'30.12"E, 28d34'52.61"N)
Center      ( 3735050.000, 3177800.000) (  1d33'27.09"E, 51d24'20.50"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

They are similar but not equals... also if the proj string is the same:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Why can I not properly convert the source tif?

Are there some bugs in GRASS or gdal?

For complete information this is the output of gdainfo on the target tif:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["X",EAST],
AXIS["Y",NORTH],
EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-6109900.000000000000000,11708100.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GRASS GIS 7.2.1 with GDAL 2.1.2
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-6109900.000,11708100.000) ( 54d53'10.20"W, 71d52'27.93"N)
Lower Left  (-6109900.000, 2852200.000) ( 54d53'10.20"W, 24d48'29.38"N)
Upper Right ( 6700300.000,11708100.000) ( 60d11'23.35"E, 71d52'27.93"N)
Lower Right ( 6700300.000, 2852200.000) ( 60d11'23.35"E, 24d48'29.38"N)
Center      (  295200.000, 7280150.000) (  2d39' 6.58"E, 54d34'36.27"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
```

UPDATE: using --debug on and suppressing -s_srs. The resulting tif is the same:

```
GDAL: GDALOpen(results_last_update/prediction_14.tif, 
this=0x750de5a6d0) succeeds as GTiff.
OGRCT: PROJ >= 4.8.0 features enabled
OGRCT: Using locale-safe proj version
OGRCT: Source: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 
+y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 
+x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 
+x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 
+y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000         +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0     +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
Creating output file that is 128102P x 88559L.
GDAL:     GDALDriver::Create(GTiff,idi/prediction_14_2.tif,128102,88559,1,Float32,0x750de30b70)
Processing input file results_last_update/prediction_14.tif.
WARP: Copying metadata from first source to destination dataset
GDAL: GDALDefaultOverviews::OverviewScan()
Using internal nodata values (e.g. nan) for image     results_last_update/prediction_14.tif.
Copying nodata values from source     results_last_update/prediction_14.tif to destination     idi/prediction_14_2.tif.
WARP: srcNoData=nan dstNoData=nan
WARP: calling GDALSetRasterNoDataValue() for band#0
OGRCT: Source: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0     +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
OGRCT: Source: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
OGRCT: Target: +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
GDAL: Start chunk 0.
GDAL: Start chunk 1.
0GDAL: GDAL_CACHEMAX = 797 MB
GDAL: Finished chunk 0.
GDAL: Start chunk 2.
...
```

I have tried with a smaller area and gdalwarp seems to works. Maybe the boundin box of the resulting tif is not correct? I'm trying to find the largest bounding box.

Comment: If I use gdalwarp on an input tif, this is correctly reprojected  and displayed so I think the problem is caused by GRASS (r.gdal.out )

Comment: Have you tried to use gdalwarp without -s_srs ? Adding `--debug on` at the end of the command may give more info.

Comment: have you tried proj string instead of epsg ?

Comment: `gdalwarp -tr 100 100  -tap  -t_srs "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs" -co SPARSE_OK=TRUE -co predictor=2 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS source.tif target.tif` same result

Comment: Your original tifs had a nodata value of zero. Perhaps you should assign that when creating your source tif.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. At the end I user R to read the target tif. I noticed that there was values. It is just a QGIS problem of visualization. Thanks anyway

Comment: For such type of pixel value you need to create statistics (min, max, std deviations etc.) using QGIS or gdalinfo -stats command. And use min-max histogram stretch. By default QGIS not stretch you Float values to visible 0 - 255 RGB values. Anyhow you need to setup raster visualisation style.